# Mule persistent object store backed by database

Tags: database, object, mule, store

Anyone know how to implement persistent object store to database In Mule? i.e. an object store used mule's interface, but backed by some database, e.g. Oracle

Comment: I saw there is one JdbcObjectStore, but don't know how to use it via Mule XML config? or need to do it by code? Thank you very much Gurus!

Comment: I have a added a answer with complete configuration for your reference

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete configuration to use a object store backed by a database in this case MySQL.

The table looks like the below

```
CREATE TABLE `objectstore` (
  `keyy` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`keyy`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

<spring:beans> 
        <spring:bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
            <spring:property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></spring:property>  
            <spring:property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"></spring:property>  
            <spring:property name="username" value="root"></spring:property>  
            <spring:property name="password" value="root"></spring:property>  
            <spring:property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="50"></spring:property>  
            <spring:property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="10"></spring:property>  
            <spring:property name="acquireIncrement" value="10"></spring:property>  
            <spring:property name="partitionCount" value="3"></spring:property>  
            <spring:property name="statementsCacheSize" value="20"></spring:property>  
        </spring:bean>  
        <spring:bean name="jdbcStore" class="org.mule.transport.jdbc.store.JdbcObjectStore"> 
            <spring:property name="jdbcConnector" ref="jdbcConnector"></spring:property>  
            <spring:property name="insertQueryKey" value="insertQueryKey"></spring:property>  
            <spring:property name="selectQueryKey" value="selectQueryKey"></spring:property>  
            <spring:property name="deleteQueryKey" value="deleteQueryKey"></spring:property>  
            <spring:property name="clearQueryKey" value="clearQueryKey"></spring:property>  
        </spring:bean>  
    </spring:beans>
    <jdbc-ee:connector name="jdbcConnector" pollingFrequency="1000" dataSource-ref="dataSource" transactionPerMessage="false" doc:name="Database"> 
        <jdbc-ee:query key="insertQueryKey" value="insert into objectstore (keyy,value) values (?,?)"></jdbc-ee:query>  
        <jdbc-ee:query key="selectQueryKey" value="select key,value from objectstore where keyy = ?"></jdbc-ee:query>  
        <jdbc-ee:query key="deleteQueryKey" value="delete from objectstore where keyy = ?"></jdbc-ee:query>
        <jdbc-ee:query key="clearQueryKey" value="delete from objectstore"></jdbc-ee:query>   
    </jdbc-ee:connector>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"></http:listener-config>

    <objectstore:config name="ObjectStore" doc:name="ObjectStore" objectStore-ref="jdbcStore"></objectstore:config>

    <flow name="persistent-tokenFlow"> 
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="insert" doc:name="HTTP"></http:listener>  
        <set-variable variableName="key" value="new key" doc:name="key"></set-variable>  
        <set-variable variableName="value" value="new value" doc:name="value"></set-variable>  
        <objectstore:store config-ref="ObjectStore" key="#[flowVars.key]" value-ref="#[flowVars.value]" doc:name="ObjectStore"></objectstore:store>  
    </flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sudarshan's example is great. Just be aware that `org.mule.transport.jdbc.store.JdbcObjectStore` does not implement `org.mule.api.store.ListableObjectStore` and will throw an exception if you're using the `allKeys` operation.

The following post shows an example of implementing ListableObjectStore:

http://www.ricston.com/blog/mule-object-store-jdbc/

The repo referred to in the post:

https://github.com/Ricston/mule-object-store-jdbc

**TL;DR**, copy-paste JdbcObjectStore in your own class which implements ListableObjectStore (cannot extend its private fields), and add the following:

```java
protected ColumnListHandler listHandler = new ColumnListHandler();

protected String allKeysQueryKey;

public String getAllKeysQueryKey() {
    return allKeysQueryKey;
}

public void setAllKeysQueryKey(String allKeysQueryKey) {
    this.allKeysQueryKey = allKeysQueryKey;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Serializable> allKeys() throws ObjectStoreException {
    String allKeysQuery = this.getAllKeysQuery();
    List<String> result = (List<String>) this.query(allKeysQuery, this.listHandler);
        return new ArrayList<Serializable>(result);
}

@Override
public void open() throws ObjectStoreException {
    // no need to implement: JdbcConnector should take care of opening connection to data source
}

@Override
public void close() throws ObjectStoreException {
    // no need to implement: JdbcConnector should take care of closing connection to data source
}
```

Continuing on Sudarshan's example, you'd then add the following setting to your jdbcStore:

```xml
<spring:property name="allKeysQueryKey" value="allKeysQueryKey" />
```

and the following query to your jdbcConnector:

```xml
<jdbc-ee:query key="allKeysQueryKey" value="select keyy from objectstore"></jdbc-ee:query>
```

P.S it's also convenient to add a Transformer to this class, to which you could assign Mule's byte-array-to-object transformer. That way you can avoid explicitly adding one to your flows after each `allKeys` operation. Post / repo above has an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

You would implement one by extending [AbstractObjectStore](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.4.2/core/src/main/java/org/mule/util/store/AbstractObjectStore.java) or one of its subclasses. I have never used the JdbcObjectStore myself, but there is at least one example configuration that you can look at to get an idea of how it is configured with a JdbcConnector and required queries: http://mulesoft.github.io/sap-transport/